# How to automatically start all data insert after header rows in sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have copied data rows from sheet 1, I would like to insert data into sheet 2, would VBA allow for me to start paste of new data in sheet 2, ten rows down?

My script:

```
Sub AddDataOnSheet2TenRowsDown()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long



    Set Results = Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow = Results.Cells(Results.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A2:B122,C2:d122").Copy
    Results.Range("A" & lastRow + 10).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll


    Application.DataEntryMode = False


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Page " & 
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Index & " of " & 
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Page " & 
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Index & " of " & 
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count




End Sub
```

Comment: Does this code work? Are you getting any errors when you step through the code?

Comment: @ Zack E, code works, however, after data is copied on Sheet2 down rows, the next page of data starts on "A1" and I would like my script to set data on row "A10" due to the default format headers, page break and do the same on Sheet 3, 4, continuous.   If you have any other questions, please do ask. Thank you

Comment: CHANGE: Results.Range("A" & lastRow + 122).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Comment: one change i would make is to clearly identify the sheet and range that are being copied.  I would change `Range("A2:B122,C2:d122").Copy` to `Sheet1.Range("A2:B122,C2:d122").Copy`  You will want to change the `Sheet1` to the codename of the sheet you are copying from though.

Comment: @Zack E, not very clear on your reply solution, I did try changing my code to Sheet1.Range("A2:B122,C2:d122").Copy, I got an error-time error '91":   Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Declare the sheet you will be copying from like you did with the Results worksheet.  Also is there data in every cell in this range `Range("A2:B122,C2:d122").Copy`?

Comment: Yes there is data in every cell Range("A2:B122,C2:D122").Copy